# Linux command that lists processes one per line

Tags: linux, command-line, process

Is there a way to restrict the output of, say 
`ps aux | grep word`, so that each process is displayed on a separate *single* line?

I need this, because my processes descriptions take up a lot of lines and I don't have good visibility when listing them with the above command. I would be happy to see just the first line of each process' representation.

Comment: Configure your terminal to not wrap lines or cut the lines manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, each process is already displayed on a single line, that's why `grep` shows that much info.

If you are willing to sacrifice the amount of details that the "COMMAND" column of `ps aux` offers, you may trim the output as such:

```
ps aux | awk '/word/ {print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$9"\t"$11}'
```

The `awk` looks for lines containing pattern 'word' and prints:

the USER, PID, %CPU, %MEM, START and first string (delimited by space)from the COMMAND column, all separated by TAB('\t')

Answer (score 1):

You may find the `pstree` command useful. It lists all processes as a tree diagram.

Comment: This is for sure a very useful command, thanks for sharing it. Unfortunately, my java processes seem to be listed as a single line `├─java───98*[{java}]` under `systemd` . I will definitely use it, though.

Answer (score 1):

When `ps aux` output is directed to a terminal, the command limits the command part to the width of the screen.

When the output is piped to a command, the behavior vary but usually, the width is unlimited. If you want to limit it the same way, you can use that command:

```
ps aux --witdh ${COLUMNS:-80} | grep word
```

Of course, if `word` isn't in the displayed characters but in the truncated ones, this won't fly.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
ps aux | awk '/word/ {print substr($0,1,'${COLUMNS:-80}')}'

ps -up $(pgrep -f word|tr '\n' ','| sed 's/,$//')
```